# Redux-form values accessing

Tags: react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm trying to set pagination on page with dynamic input setting of the pageSize
using redux-form library, I set pageSize using selectors and mapping them into props,
but in order to set pagination I'm in need of that pageSize value in my other reducer (
not form reducer ), and I cant get how to access it

```
// Reducer

import { FETCH, SHOW_GRID, SHOW_LIST, SET_PAGINATION } from "./types";
import { data } from "../data";

const initialData = {
  fetchedData: data,
  listSelected: true,
  pageSizeOptions: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
};

export default function (state = initialData, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_GRID:
      return {
        ...state,
        listSelected: false,
      };
    case SHOW_LIST:
      return {`enter code here`
        ...state,
        listSelected: true,
      };
    case SET_PAGINATION:
      console.log(??)

    default:
      return state;
  }
}



// actions

import { FETCH, SHOW_GRID, SHOW_LIST, SET_PAGINATION } from "./types";

export function fetch() {
  return {
    type: FETCH,
  };
}

export function showGrid() {
  return {
    type: SHOW_GRID,
  };
}
export function showList() {
  return {
    type: SHOW_LIST,
  };
}

export function setPagination() {
  return {
    type: SET_PAGINATION,
  };
}

// The component itself

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm, Field, formValueSelector } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getFormValues } from "redux-form";
import { setPagination } from "../store/actions";

class PageSize extends Component {
  render() {
    const pageSizeOptions = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
    return (
      <Field
        component="select"
        name="pageSize"
        defaultValue={4}
        onChange={setPagination}
      >
        {pageSizeOptions.map((val) =>
          val == this.props.pageSize ? (
            <option name={val} value={val} selected>
              {val}
            </option>
          ) : (
            <option value={val}>{val}</option>
          )
        )}
      </Field>
    );
  }
}
export const ReduxFormComponent = reduxForm({
  form: "pageSize",
})(PageSize);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const selector = formValueSelector("pageSize");
  const selectedPageSize = selector(state, "pageSize");
  return {
    pageSize: selectedPageSize,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setPagination,
};

const component = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ReduxFormComponent);

export default connect((state) => ({
  values: getFormValues("pageSize")(state),
}))(component);
```

Comment: I tried to watch that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478786/how-do-you-access-the-values-from-a-redux-form-in-a-reducer but it wasn't successful for me. The only things i changed are const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setPagination: (values) => {
    console.log(values);
    dispatch({ type: SET_PAGINATION, payload: values });
  },
});

Comment: And set my Field like this <Field
        component="select"
        name="pageSize"
        defaultValue={4}
        onChange={() => this.props.setPagination(this.props.pageSize)}
      >    with setPagination(size) function returning {type: SET_PAGINATION, payload: size}

Comment: Last time it actually said that this.props.setPagination is not a function...

Comment: The error is: TypeError: this.props.setPagination is not a function